# Dapper: How to read into list of Dictionary from query?

Tags: c#, sql, dictionary, dapper

Dapper provides lots of ways mapping data into list of dynamic objects. However in some case I'd like to read data to list of Dictionary.

The SQL may looks like:

```
"SELECT * FROM tb_User"
```

**As tb_User may change outside, I don't know what columns will return in result.** So I can write some code like this:

```
var listOfDict = conn.QueryAsDictionary(sql);
foreach (var dict in listOfDict) {
    if (dict.Contains("anyColumn")) {
        // do right thing...
    }
}
```

Is there any built-in methods for Dapper to do this conversion?

Comment: To understand this better, you want an individual row as an `IDictionary<,>`, where key=columnName, value=columnValue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can cast each row as IDictionary:

```
    var row = (IDictionary<string, object>)conn.Query("select foo = 1, bar = 'bar'").First();

    Assert.That(row["foo"], Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(row["bar"], Is.EqualTo("bar"));
```

Comment: I tried to find documentation regarding casting `dynamic` to `IDictionary`, but couldn't find any. Does anyone have a reference?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `Cast` extension method from `System.Linq`

```
IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> rows;
rows = connection.Query(sqlRequest).Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>();

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var columnValue = row['columnName']; // returns the value of the column name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign aliases to your query so that it matches the `Key` and `Value` properties of a `KeyValuePair` and then use the `.ToDictionary` method like this:

```
var dict = db.Query<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(@"
    SELECT COMMUNITY_TYPE As Key, COUNT(*) AS Value
    FROM SNCOMM.COMMUNITY
    GROUP BY COMMUNITY_TYPE")
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Now you have a `Dictionary<string, int>` without any manual converting.